# How to configure extensions Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using an extension called Error Lens and want to turn off inline messages.  This person has the same issue (https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/usernamehw/vscode-error-lens/60/703069563) and the response is a line of code:

```
"errorLens.messageEnabled": false,
```

Feeling daft but I can't work out where to modify or input this code?  Thanks for the advice

Comment: have looked at the VSC doc pages for `Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the *command palette* via <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac or navigate to *View* → *Command Palette...*.
Now type "*Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)*" and press enter. This will open the VS Code's settings as JSON file. There you can insert the above line of code.

If you prefer VS Code's settings GUI you can run the command "*Preferences: Open Settings (UI)*" instead. Now a GUI is shown. You can search the GUI for specific settings. Inserting "*errorLens.messageEnabled*" in the search field should lead you to the corresponding setting (a checkbox) in the GUI which you then can (un-)check.